# EF Core Union query with anonymous types mismatch

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

This feels like an unusual bug in (Oracle) EF Core, but I'm unsuccessful in finding something like it yet.

To reproduce this problem, let's assume 2 simple models as properties on a parent - Parent, ChildA and ChildB, where ChildA and ChildB are identical:

```cs
public class Parent 
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public IList<ChildA> childrenA = new List<ChildA>();
    public IList<ChildB> childrenB = new List<ChildB>();
}
```

```cs
public class ChildA  // or ChildB
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public int ValueA { get; private set; }
    public int ValueB { get; private set; }
    public decimal? ValueC { get; private set; }
    public decimal? ValueD { get; private set; }
}
```

I have the following query:

```cs
var parent = dbContext.Set<Parent>.AsNoTracking();

var query = parent.SelectMany(p => p.childrenA.Select(child => new
    child.Id,
    A = child.ValueA,
    B = child.ValueB,
    C = child.ValueC,
    D = child.ValueD
  }).Union(p.childrenB.Where(x => someWhereClause).Select(child => new
    child.Id,
    A = child.ValueA,
    B = child.ValueB,
    C = (decimal?) null,
    D = (decimal?) null
  })));

var queryString = query.ToQueryString();
```

However, when executing this at run time against my Oracle DB, I get the following:

> ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file

Which after investigating, is caused by EF Core being unable to translate the query:

> Unable to translate set operation when matching columns on both sides have different store types.

Where if I separate the queries and call `.ToQueryString()`, it seems in the second query the `D` value is being excluded in the resulting `SELECT`.

By changing the `(decimal?) null` values in the anonymous type of the second query to actual column references, it seems to correctly add the values in and the queries work.

What might be the cause of this, and am I doing something wrong? I want to intentionally conceal those values in the query.

Currently running .NET 6.0, Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore@6.21.61, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore@6.0.10

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fixed in [EF Core 8](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19129)

Comment: Cheers @SvyatoslavDanyliv - add this as an answer and I'll mark it as resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This long standing issue is fixed only in EF Core 8.

GitHub issue to track: [Set operations over non-entity projections with different facets](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19129)